# How can I synchronize civimail and my microsoft outlook mail program?

Tags: civimail

As response mails arrive in my "normal" outlook account, I'd like to see them automatically on civicrm in order to have a better overview. Is there a possibility to create a folder in outlook that updates mails in civicrm?

thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to create a special response email address and then use CiviCRM's email-to-activity functionality to attach them to your CiviCRM contact records. You could also make a folder in your IMAP account and let that folder be imported into CiviCRM.

http://book.civicrm.org/user/advanced-configuration/email-system-configuration/

*From the book:*

> **Email-to-Activity processing**
>
> CiviCRM can automatically retrieve email from a specified inbox and file it as an email activity against contacts corresponding to sender and recipients of the email. New contacts are created for emails not already in the database.
>
> There are two ways to do this (either or both ways can be setup at same time):
>
> - **Special email address:** Set up a special email address for your organization, e.g. civiemails@example.com. Users can then add this address in the Bcc field for your outbound emails; they will get auto filed in CiviCRM as described above. No one who receives the email will see this special address if the Bcc field is used.
> - **IMAP Folder:** Set up a folder in your IMAP Inbox where you can drag emails that you want filed in CiviCRM.Â  This works with both inbound and outbound emails. (this requires that your email be set up using IMAP.)

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use our outlook plugin and extension. The extension will let you file emails into CiviCRM from your outlook client and it will also create contacts where needed. Its a bit more powerful than activity to email as it will let you pick from duplicate civicrm contacts and it also lets you create/update cases from emails too.

You can see more about the functions [here](http://www.vedaconsulting.co.uk/outlookforcivicrm-release) and [here](http://www.vedaconsulting.co.uk/outlookforcivicrm-civicase)